# Programmatically created UILabel not appearing in IOS 7 storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, storyboard, ios7

Basically my simple problem is programmatically created UILabel **not appearing in IOS 7 simulator but it work on IOS 6 simulator** and I'm using **storyboard**

my code is:

```
 UILabel *lbl_top = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 100, 100)];
    lbl_top.text = text;
    lbl_top.font = customFont;
    lbl_top.numberOfLines = 1;
    lbl_top.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines; 
    lbl_top.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    lbl_top.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = YES;
    lbl_top.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
    lbl_top.clipsToBounds = YES;
    lbl_top.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lbl_top.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    lbl_top.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    lbl_top.hidden = FALSE;
    lbl_top.alpha = 1.0;
    [self.view addSubview:lbl_top];
```

consol Print :

Printing description of lbl_top:

UILabel: 0x8dae430; frame = (10 100; 100 100); text = 'Power issues - Power Surv...'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = CALayer: 0x8db5f30

In IOS 6 Simulator

[image: In IOS 6 Simulator]

In IOS 7 Simulator

[image: In IOS 7 Simulator]

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct code for those images? I don't see the black background. Also 'adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth' is deprecated on iOS 7.

Comment: @Odrakir sorry i edit it

Comment: That works on iOS 7. Maybe there's something wrong with the code where you generate your custom font or your text.

Comment: @Odrakir i figure it out that issue is viewWillAppear that work on IOS 6 but not in IOS 7 thanks for giving clue of view didLoad function

Answer (score 1):

```
try this code 

UILabel *lbl_top = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 100, 100)];
lbl_top.text = @"agssudass ";
lbl_top.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
lbl_top.numberOfLines = 1;
lbl_top.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
lbl_top.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
lbl_top.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = YES;
lbl_top.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
lbl_top.clipsToBounds = YES;
lbl_top.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lbl_top.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lbl_top.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
lbl_top.hidden = FALSE;
lbl_top.alpha = 1.0;
[self.view addSubview:lbl_top];
```

changes are

```
lbl_top.text = @"agssudass ";
lbl_top.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lbl_top.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0]; 
lbl_top.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't set the text for that label proparly.
set the text like

```
lolabel.text = @"Welcome";
```

and once check your font also may be your font is not supporting in `iOS 7`.
Once change the font to default font and check it out.